# R: reestructurar una tabla

Tags: r

De una tabla como esta:

```
     ID       POS            REF    ALT   AD_REF_P      AD_ALT_P     
     Pop1    Locus1          A      G      0             10 
     Pop1    Locus2          A      G      0             10
     Pop2    Locus1          A      G      1              9
     Pop2    Locus3          C      T      6              4
```

Me gustaría generar una tabla como esta, de tal manera que en la Pop1 aparezca 10 veces y de esas diez aparezcan 10 G en la columna de Locus1 y 10 G en la columna de Locus 2 y por otro lado Pop2 aparezca otras diez veces, con 1 A y 9 G en la columna locus 1 y 6 C y 4 T en la columna Locus 3.

```
      Pop       Locus1      Locus2        Locus3
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop1       G            G              0
      Pop2       A            0              C
      Pop2       G            0              C
      Pop2       G            0              C
      Pop2       G            0              C
      Pop2       G            0              C
      Pop2       G            0              C
      Pop2       G            0              T
      Pop2       G            0              T
      Pop2       G            0              T
      Pop2       G            0              T
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esta tabla?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero te sirva el siguiente código

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)


#Leemos los datos
df<-tibble::tribble(
~ID,   ~POS,~REF,  ~ALT,  ~AD_REF_P,~AD_ALT_P,   
"Pop1","Locus1",  "A",  "G",  0, 10, 
"Pop1","Locus2",  "A",  "G",  0, 10,
"Pop2","Locus1",  "A", "G",  1,  9,
"Pop2","Locus3",  "C",  "T",  6,  4 )


#Creamos una nueva variable v3 donde se repita cada letra el número de veces necesario por locus
aux<-df%>%rowwise(.)%>%
    mutate(v1=paste(rep(REF,AD_REF_P),collapse = "-"),
            v2=paste(rep(ALT,AD_ALT_P),collapse = "-"),
            v3=paste(v1,v2,sep="-"),
            N=str_count(v3,"-")+1)%>%
  select(-REF,-ALT,-AD_REF_P,-AD_ALT_P,-v1,-v2)


N<-max(aux$N) #Numero máximo de letras (+1 creo) 
N2<-2+N #este sera el número de columnas de aux en un punto más adelante

aux<-aux%>%
  select(-N)%>% 
  separate(v3,paste0("x",1:N))%>% #Separamos las letras de v3 en columnas llamadas x1..xN
  gather("V1","L",3:N2)%>% #Pasamos a formato largo estas columnas
  spread(POS,L)%>% #Ahora a formato ancho de acuerdo a Poss
  select(-V1) #Quitamos V1

#Hcemos 0 los datos faltantes
aux[is.na(aux)]<-0 
aux[aux==""]<-0
aux<-aux%>%filter(!(Locus1==0&Locus2==0&Locus3==0))
```

#Queda así

```
aux
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   ID    Locus1 Locus2 Locus3
   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
 1 Pop1  G      G      0     
 2 Pop1  G      G      0     
 3 Pop1  G      G      0     
 4 Pop1  G      G      0     
 5 Pop1  G      G      0     
 6 Pop1  G      G      0     
 7 Pop1  G      G      0     
 8 Pop1  G      G      0     
 9 Pop1  G      G      0     
10 Pop1  G      G      0     
11 Pop2  A      0      C     
12 Pop2  G      0      T     
13 Pop2  G      0      C     
14 Pop2  G      0      C     
15 Pop2  G      0      C     
16 Pop2  G      0      C     
17 Pop2  G      0      C     
18 Pop2  G      0      T     
19 Pop2  G      0      T     
20 Pop2  G      0      T
```

Comment: El script funciona! muchas gracias